# Custom LiteralControl does not insert into page

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, inheritance, webforms

I am tired of creating a System.Web.UI.LiteralControl everytime I need to add a   control to my  in webforms.  So, I decided that it would help me if I created a custom LiteralControl that initialized with that value.

So, I created this very simple class:

```
    Public Class ScriptLiteralControl
    Inherits System.Web.UI.LiteralControl

    Private _Text As String

    Public Sub New()
        Me.InitControl()
    End Sub

    Private Sub InitControl()
        Me._Text = "<script type=""text/none""></script>"
    End Sub

    Public Overrides Property Text As String
        Get
            Return Me._Text
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            Me._Text = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

But when I do this in my webpages:

```
dim slc as New ScriptLiteralControl
Me.Header.Controls.Add(slc)
```

Absolutely nothing gets added.

According to the ASP.NET documentation I've read, all I had to do was basically override the Text property in my implementation but that doesn't seem to be working.

Can someone tell me what obscure .net rule I am not following in my implementation?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have to override the Text property. I think that's what's causing your problem. Try this:

`Public Class ScriptLiteralControl
    Inherits System.Web.UI.LiteralControl
         Public Sub New()
              Me.Text = "Put your script text here"
         End Sub
    End Class`